# Make paragraph text wrap round image if text and image are in two separate <div>s?

Tags: css

Consider the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="field field-type-date field-field-event-date">
    <div class="field-items">
      <div class="field-item odd">
        <span class="date-display-single">Fri 24 Jun 2011</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>
    Don't miss your chance to see the incredible artwork produced by this year's Creative Arts students at Fareham College.
  </p>
  <p>
    The exhibition will be held on the College campus, featuring work from our Art, Graphic Design, Photography, Fashion and Media students.
  </p>
  <p>
    This event runs on weekdays from 10am–4pm on 24th June–1th July 2011 in both the A-Block and the Function Room at Fareham College.
  </p>
  <p>
    We look forward to seeing you.
  </p>
  <div class="field field-type-filefield field-field-event-image">
    <div class="field-items">
      <div class="field-item odd">
        <img class="imagefield imagefield-field_event_image" width="188" height="266" alt="" src="http://www.fareham.ac.uk/sites/default/files/creative-arts-summer-exhibition.jpg?1310378590">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the actual page with the above code in action: http://www.fareham.ac.uk/events/2011/06/creative-arts-summer-exhibition

Is it possible to float the image to one side and have the text wrap around it? If so, how can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: can you move the image above the text?

Comment: I've no doubt this is possible, but I haven't figured out how to make Drupal do this as yet.

Comment: Don't do that! You can achieve what you are trying to do with styles alone (see my response) - the HTML should not be changed to achieve a certain style plus there is SEO value in having relevant content higher up (okay, in this instance it wouldn't probably matter but in principle it's good practice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move your `<div>` tag containing your image above your paragraphs and then float left or right then that will cause the text to wrap around your image.
 Like so,

```
<div class="content">
<div class="field field-type-date field-field-event-date">
<div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item odd">
                <span class="date-display-single">Fri 24 Jun 2011</span>        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="field field-type-filefield field-field-event-image" style="float: right;">
<div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item odd">
                <img class="imagefield imagefield-field_event_image quimby_search_image" width="188" height="266" alt="" src="http://www.fareham.ac.uk/sites/default/files/creative-arts-summer-exhibition.jpg?1310378590">        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p>Don't miss your chance to see the incredible artwork produced by this year's Creative Arts students at Fareham College.</p>
<p>The exhibition will be held on the College campus, featuring work from our Art, Graphic Design, Photography, Fashion and Media students.</p>
<p>This event runs on weekdays from 10am–4pm on 24th June–1th July 2011 in both the A-Block and the Function Room at Fareham College.</p>
<p>We look forward to seeing you.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was afraid of, I've no idea how to achieve this with Drupal. The Drupal 'Themeing Guide' is making my head spin.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this sooner, but I changed the order of page elements here: `/admin/content/node-type/event/fields`, which allowed me to float the image using CSS. For what it's worth, this can also be achieved with the Panels module. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it: Wrap your paragraphs in a div and put the following styles on it;

```
<div style = "float:right; width: 70%">
  <p>....</p>
  <p>....</p>
  <p>....</p>
</div>
```

I've tried on the page you linked and it works in firefox. You didn't specify which way around you wanted them, so this just assumes you wanted image on left text on right. Any questions let me know.

Also don't do the style inline like i have, that was just to demonstrate :)

Comment: Thanks for this, Mikey. Is there anyway to do this with more precision, rather than 70%, have the text sit 20px from the image?

Comment: you could use: `width:400px;padding-right:20px;`  `px` is pixels

Comment: beware box model nightmares in IE if you're specifying both a fixed width and padding though!